# Use of Begin tran in a stored procedure which include update statements and a CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

My stored procedure structure is as shown below and I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.

If I remove `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` statements then stored procedure runs fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me with understanding what is wrong and what should be the right approach?

```
Create PROCEDURE proc_name(param1,param2,param3)
AS
Begin
with cte(col1, col2, col3)
AS
(
Select col1
,col2
,col3
from table1
)
Begin Tran
Update table2
set col1 = 'text'
from table2 inner join cte on cte.hmy = table2.hmy
where some condition

update table3
set date = ''
from table3 inner join cte on cte.hmy = table3.hmy
where some different condition

COMMIT TRAN

END
```

*P.S. Please ignore the query logic. I tried to simplified the code by removing business logic.*

Comment: Tried it just now. Still the same error.

Comment: You can't place `BEGIN TRAN` in the middle of a CTE, just surround the CTE with the `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`.

Comment: @Lankymart I have placed begin tran after completion of CTE. is it wrong?

Comment: It depends what you are wanting to do. If you just wanted to effect the first update then you would place `BEGIN TRAN` before the `WITH` and `COMMIT TRAN` after the first `UPDATE` statement *(as that is part of the CTE)*. Otherwise just wrap both the CTE and second `UPDATE` inside `BEGIN TRAN` ... `COMMIT TRAN` statements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have `BEGIN TRAN` *in the middle of* a CTE, move the transaction outside of the CTE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name(param1,param2,param3)
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN

    ;WITH cte(col1, col2, col3)
    AS
    (
      SELECT col1
      ,col2
      ,col3
      FROM table1
    )
    UPDATE table2
    SET col1 = 'text'
    FROM table2 INNER JOIN cte ON cte.hmy = table2.hmy
    WHERE some condition

    UPDATE table3
    SET date = ''
    FROM table3 INNER JOIN cte ON cte.hmy = table3.hmy
    WHERE some different condition

  COMMIT TRAN
END
```

You could also legally apply the transaction just to the CTE but the second `UPDATE` would not be included in the transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name(param1,param2,param3)
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN

    ;WITH cte(col1, col2, col3)
    AS
    (
      SELECT col1
      ,col2
      ,col3
      FROM table1
    )
    UPDATE table2
    SET col1 = 'text'
    FROM table2 INNER JOIN cte ON cte.hmy = table2.hmy
    WHERE some condition

  COMMIT TRAN

  -- UPDATE will run but not part of the transaction.
  UPDATE table3
  SET date = ''
  FROM table3 INNER JOIN cte ON cte.hmy = table3.hmy
  WHERE some different condition
END
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. waiting for 4 mins to mark it as solution :)

Comment: how can the updates work when CTE can be used only in one statement?

Comment: Also note the ; (semi colon) before the `WITH`